# How do I determine employee's most current dateofEntry?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Each employee is given an opportunity to record date of visit up to 3 visits.

How do I determine employee's most current date of visit and add 3 years to it?

I tried the following:

```
select top 1 dateOfVisit from table 
  where empid=123 
  Order by dateOfVisit DESC
```

This isn't giving me most current date of visit.

Then I would need to add 3 years to it.

Comment: If it isn't giving you the most current date of visit, what is it giving you? The SQL looks fine for a single employee. Can you show a few rows of sample data and desired results? Also what is the data type of `dateOfVisit`?

Comment: can you show a sample of what you have now that isn't working, so we can follow along at home? Maybe use sqlfiddle.com to build a basic example for us that's interactive, so we know what's broken

Comment: I'm bowing out. FAR too annoying for me.

Comment: PS Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b15b/1/2) showing all three queries below. Take a look and edit it if you need to discuss something.**

Adding 3 years can be done using [DATEADD()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
  select top (1) DATEADD(year, 3, dateOfVisit) [DateOfVisitPlus3Years]
    from [table]
   where empid=123
order by dateOfVisit DESC;
```

---

You have used the singular form "employee" in the title and various times in the text, as well as providing a query for a single employee.  But on the remote possibility that you actually need this across multiple employees, just use MAX()

```
  select empid, DATEADD(year, 3, max(dateOfVisit)) [DateOfVisitPlus3Years]
    from [table]
group by empid;
```

---

The below query gives you the number of days that have elapsed between the last (most recent) dateOfVisit, per employee, from the current date (i.e. "*today*")

```
  select empid,
         DATEDIFF(day, max(dateOfVisit), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) [DaysSinceLastVisit]
    from [table]
group by empid;
```

Comment: `The spec actually is to get the latest dateOfVisit and substract current date from it.` Then your question title and description bears no semblance to your requirements. Then again, this is not a site for **requirements** per-se since we are not **work-for-hire**.  Instead, if you have a problem you need help with, then by all means post a *description of the issue* you are having.

Comment: Everybody PLEASE calm down. I have already accepted responsibility for the mistake and apologized for it.What do you want me to do? I posted incorrect question based on wrong understanding of the problem. Aaron, the code you guys posted worked fine based on what I asked for initially. It was not wrong.

When you get this overly annoyed, it negatives all your nice deeds.

Thanks alot @Richard.